# Writing the data to CSV file

Tags: shell, scripting, csv, xml

I have a file generated everyday which have number of webservices request and response and i wanted to write the contents of the request and response to the CSV file.

Something in the below format (Contents of both request and response together)

```
phonenumber,RefID,DateTime,SOATransactionID,phonenumber,RefID
```

Please note that only Phonenumber,RefID,DateTime to be extracted in the Input Request and SOATransactionID,phonenumber,RefID to be extracted in the Output response.

Sample request & Reponse

```
#######################Input Request#######################
</soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body>
        <cre:Customer>
            <cre:account>
                <cor:phonenumber>7654899089</cor:phonenumber>
            </cre:account>
            <cre:RefID>ABC1234</cre:RefID>
            <cre:DateTime>2002-04-20T00:00:06.774+01:00</cre:DateTime>
        </cre:Customer>
    </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
#######################Output Response#######################
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cor="http://reftest.com/coredata1"><soapenv:Header><cor:SOATransactionID>123-456-890</cor:SOATransactionID></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://reftest.com/Testdata1"><ns3:successResponse><ns3:account><cor:phonenumber>7654899089</cor:phonenumber></ns3:account><ns3:RefID>ABC1234</ns3:RefID></ns3:successResponse></ns3:Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
#######################Input Request#######################
</soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body>
        <cre:Customer>
            <cre:account>
                <cor:phonenumber>8766769089</cor:phonenumber>
            </cre:account>
            <cre:RefID>ABC1234</cre:RefID>
            <cre:DateTime>2002-04-20T00:00:06.774+01:00</cre:DateTime>
        </cre:Customer>
    </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
#######################Output Response#######################
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cor="http://reftest.com/coredata1"><soapenv:Header><cor:SOATransactionID>123-456-890</cor:SOATransactionID></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://reftest.com/Testdata1"><ns3:successResponse><ns3:account><cor:phonenumber>8766769089</cor:phonenumber></ns3:account><ns3:RefID>ABC1234</ns3:RefID></ns3:successResponse></ns3:Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @PhilipR. Please try to state what you've tried so far and the problem(s) you ran into and somebody might help you out. That's mostly how this works. Also check if your question is on topic here (Unix and Linux).

Comment: Also, please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make your question more readable (in particular the sample input and output, which should be in ["block code" formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)).

Comment: Are you able to generate the XML document without the non-XML annotations (the timestamps and `[INFO]` bits). What you are showing looks rather like a log file.  Also, there doesn't seem to be anything connecting a `UsernamToken` with a `Customer` section, and there are end tags for a `Body` node that seems totally incomplete.  Did you perform some (text-) processing on this that produced this broken XML?